# Gmail Notifier for Windows 7 showing "No Unread Mail"

Tags: windows-7, email, gmail

My Gmail Notifier on a Windows 7 machine is showing "No Unread Mail." As a matter of fact, though, I have many new unread messages in my inbox.

Opening up my Inbox in Mozilla Thunderbird or Gmail's website works normally, and shows new mail.

What can I do to fix the Notifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're speaking of the actual Google Notifier application (there's a 3rd party app called "Gmail Notifier") then it's probably because Google dropped support for the Google Notifier at the end of January (2014).

Basically, they suggest you use the Chrome browser instead.

From Google:

> Google Notifier Beta is no longer supported. If you want to continue
>   to receive notifications, you can use any of the following
>   alternatives to Google Notifier Beta using the Chrome browser...

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10960?hl=en)

> ...Google thought the same thing, and today quietly discontinued the free tool, which has been around
>   since 2005. Users looking to install the app are now being told by
>   Google to simply install Chrome, which has desktop notifications built
>   in...

[Source](http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/16/5316748/google-quietly-kills-off-its-notifier-service-for-mail-and-calendar)

Notice sent to users by Google a couple weeks in advance:

> Important Announcement on Google Notifier Beta
>
> We are writing to let
>   you know about an important change to Google Notifier Beta. Starting
>   on January 31, 2014, Google Notifier Beta will no longer be supported,
>   meaning the app will no longer show recent emails and calendar events.
>
> Since the Google Notifier Beta launched in 2005, a lot has changed.
>   Smart phones can now notify us of new messages wherever we are, and
>   improvements to web technology enable similar features to be built
>   right into the browser.
>
> If you want to continue to receive notifications, you can use any of
>   the following alternatives to Google Notifier Beta using the Chrome
>   browser:
>
> To see the number of unread messages in your inbox at a glance,
>   install the Gmail Checker Chrome app. To preview new messages on your
>   desktop, go to Gmail's settings and enable Desktop Notifications. To
>   get Calendar notifications on the desktop, go to Calendar's settings
>   and enable Show floating desktop notifications. You can uninstall the
>   Google Notifier Beta by following these instructions.
>
> -- The Gmail and Calendar Teams

Comment: Yes, it is the one from Google. However I can't see 'Beta' anywhere. Gmail Notifier v1.0.25.0

Comment: It's the same thing, as practically everything from Google is (endlessly) "Beta". ;)  See [Google Comments on Why Everything is Always in Beta](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/news/google_comments_why_everything_always_beta) for example.

Comment: It's sad this little app is no longer supported (I'm truly addicted to it; it should at-least still work just like any other old software). +1 for the everything is Beta link, but I hope Google would practice this mantra as a means to 'continous improvement' rather than an excuse to break things without any warning. :(

Comment: They did give warning by email, about 2 weeks in advance, see what I edited in.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail Notifier was laid to rest a few days back and thus creating an end to the desktop notification to those who have been using the service. Gmail Notifier Pro which is the replacement for the former one is meant for high-end PC users for example those running Windows 7 or newer due to the system requirements, for example .NET framework 3.5, which is not found in so many PC which are running XP and others.

As a Gmail Notifier user, I really loved the application for its easy to use interface although now its no more but still, there many webmasters have already started sharing what we can term as some alternatives and so far, I am using Popman, the one I got to know after stumbling this thread [3 gmail notifier alternatives to try.](http://www.thekonsulthub.com/alternatives/3-best-alternatives-for-gmail-notifier-now-retired/) To be honest, I like Popman even after only hours of use and am relieved. The best thing to do is switching to an alternative for Gmail Notifier.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can try this alternative:
https://github.com/xps/Gmail-Notifier-Replacement

It is an open-source, free, and very simple replacement for the standard Google Notifier, and aims as being as close to the original as possible.

*Disclaimer: I am the author.*

Comment: Thanks Xavier Poinas. I'm glad you have developed it in C#. Will check source code for possible issues and will use a custom build for myself. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate to submit pull requests if you develop anything that could be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail Notifier still working as of today 22 November 2014.

a) Uninstall your current version of Gmail Notifier
b) Install Gmail Notifier again on your computer but stop before entering any details.
c) Open your gmail account on the web and go to your account details.
d) Find Security and open it.
e) If you are running 2 step verification you need to open it.
   i) If the 'old' Gmail Notifier listed, revoke the permission.
   ii) Create another application under 'Other' and name it " Gmail Notifier"
f) Google will now provide you with a once off password, no spaces in between.
g) Enter your email address now on Notifier and type in, not copy, the Google password.
h) Bingo, Notifier in business with zero mails (0) and not (-), meaning not connected